# How to get the super class name in annotation processing

Tags: java, annotations

I run an annotation processor written by my self to generate some new java code based on annotated classes. Following is what i tried to get the super class name of a currently processed class.

```
TypeMirror superTypeMirror = typeElement.getSuperclass();
final TypeKind superClassName = superTypeMirror.getKind();
log("A==================" + superClassName.getClass());
log("B==================" + superClassName.getDeclaringClass());
```

typeElement returns me the current class that annotation processor is processing. I want to know which classes this extends and which classes are implemented by this class. The methods i used are not helpful at all.

Thankx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly,  [`Types.directSupertypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#directSupertypes%28javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror%29) is the method you need.

It will return the type of the direct superclass first, followed by the (directly) implemented interfaces, if there are any.

Regardless of whether they represent a superclass or a superinterface, you should be able to cast them to [`DeclaredType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/type/DeclaredType.html), which has an `asElement()` method, that can be used to query things as simple and fully qualified name.

So you'll have something like this:

```
for (TypeMirror supertype : Types.directSupertypes(typeElement)) {
   DeclaredType declared = (DeclaredType)supertype; //you should of course check this is possible first
   Element supertypeElement = declared.asElement();
   System.out.println( "Supertype name: " + superTypeElement.getSimpleName() );
}
```

The above works if `typeElement` is a `TypeMirror`, if it is a `TypeElement`, you can get the superclass and the superinterfaces directly by simply calling `typeElement.getSuperclass()` and `typeElement.getInterfaces()` separately ( instead of `Types.directSupertypes()`) but the rest of the process is the same.

Comment: I got the idea from you, and did it in following way.            TypeMirror superTypeMirror = typeElement.getSuperclass();
            DeclaredType declared = (DeclaredType) superTypeMirror;
            //you should of course check this is possible first
            Element supertypeElement = declared.asElement();
            note("Supertype name: " + supertypeElement.getSimpleName());

Comment: Becouse the typeElements cannot be casted to TypeMirror. So directSuperTypes will not work as it is.

Comment: @dinesh707 You're right, my mistake. But the rest was helpful at least :)

Comment: I wondered where I get `Types` from (as directSupertypes() is an instance method). In the end it was super easy: `processingEnv.getTypeUtils()` where processingEnv is a field on the `AbstractProcessor`.

Comment: Great！
```processingEnv.typeUtils.directSupertypes(element.asType())```

Answer (score -3):

You can find the super class of any Java Object through reflection. explained here http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/reflect/class/getSuperclass.html

regarding implementing classes. that's more difficult as I believe a given class never "knows" which classes extend it. You will need to build need an elaborate tree of inheritence to get the full picture.

Comment: `regarding implementing classes. that's more difficult as I believe a given class never "knows" which classes extend it.` I may have read the question wrong, but I think OP just wants the list of interfaces the current class implements (and the direct superclass)

Comment: in this case, there is getInterfaces() method for a given Class